# is it possible to stop search engines indexing pages with certain querystring parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, indexing, robots.txt, datapager

I am using the asp.net DataPager and noticed that search engines wouldn't be able to crawl the links created, so I added a querystring parameter and now see that it could crawl the links.

The problem I now have is that it will now eventially end up with multiple urls for the same page.

Is it possible to stop search engines indexing all pages with the query string parameter such as:

```
?pg=
```

so the search engine will follow these links but not index:

```
http://domain.co.uk/news/07-04-2011/bank-of-england-base-rate?pg=3
http://domain.co.uk/news/11-03-2011/client-feedback-from-employee-relocation?pg=6
```

but would index:

```
http://domain.co.uk/news/07-04-2011/bank-of-england-base-rate
http://domain.co.uk/news/11-03-2011/client-feedback-from-employee-relocation
```

Thanks for any help

J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can achieve that with a robots.txt

With google you can specify parameters you want to exclude with the webmaster tools.

You could also trap the useragent and simply crash the page when it's a bot ...

Comment: yeah i've seen the parameter exlusion, but would the bots still follow the links and just not index? as this is what i require.

Comment: @JBoom yes, they will index the page and ignore the parameters. Make sure your page is still working properly without those parameters, because google will call the page with the url minus the parameters exclusion ...

Comment: yeah the pages still work with the pages, already checked that. Will give that a go then and see how the indexing gets on once the site is live. Thanks for the information.